Question on $t_{\alpha}$ for isomorphism between H and H*
In Chapter 10.5 of "Introduction to Lie Algebras" by Karin Erdmann and Mark J. Wildon, on "Root Strings and Eigenvalues":

We can use the Killing form to define an isomorphism between $H$ and $H^*$ as follows. Given $h \in H$, let ${\theta}_h$ denote the map ${\theta}_h \in H^*$ defined by


${\theta}_h(k) = \kappa(h, k)$ for all $k \in H$.


By Lemma 10.1(iii) the Killing form is non-degenerate on restriction to $H$, so the map $h \mapsto {\theta}_h$ is an isomorphism between $H$ and $H^*$. In particular, associated to each root $\alpha \in \Phi$ there is a unique element $t_\alpha \in H$ such that


$\kappa(t_\alpha, k) = \alpha(k)$ for all $k \in H$.

My question is on the last sentence "there is a unique element $t_\alpha \in H$ such that
$\kappa(t_\alpha, k) = \alpha(k)$ for all $k \in H$.":
I understand that $h \mapsto {\theta}_h(k)$ is an isomorphism. But why not $\kappa(t_\alpha, k) = f(k) \alpha(k)$, with $f(k)$ a function depending on the underlying $k$. What makes the $f(k)$ a constant, and uniform on all $k$'s?
$\alpha$ is already defined by $[h,x] = \alpha(h) x$, with $h \in H$ and $x \in L_\alpha$. Why can we make an argument saying that this $\alpha$ corresponds exactly to $t_\alpha$, thus $\kappa(t_\alpha, k) = \alpha(k)$, with $k \in H$?
Another way to express my question:
Let's say there is a $t_{\alpha1}$ such that $\kappa(t_{\alpha1}, k_1) = \alpha (k_1)$. There is also a $t_{\alpha2}$ such that $\kappa(t_{\alpha2}, k_2) = \alpha (k_2)$. $k_1$ and $k_2$ are independent and both are in $H$. Why does $t_{\alpha1}$ equals $t_{\alpha2}$.

He showed you we have an explicit isomorphism, and so for $\alpha \in H^*$, which is a linear functional over $H$, he can pick a $t_\alpha$ satisfying the given isomorphism, which has relation $\kappa(t_\alpha,k) = \alpha(k)$ for all $k$, is this what you want to ask? The $\alpha$ was picked first, then come the existence of $t_\alpha$, so I don't understand why you want to include $f(k)$ in your computation.

There is a definition for $\alpha(k) x = [k, x]$. A definition of killing form $\kappa(t_\alpha,k) = Tr(ad t_\alpha \cdot ad k)$. And this definition $\kappa(t_\alpha,k) = \alpha(k)$. Why t_\alpha is an exact match on the already defined alpha and already defined killing form.

Ah I see yes it's quite obvious...

I added another description of my question, so hopefully now is more clear.

Your $t_{\alpha_1}$, once you found it, is fixed  and uniquely determined by the given isomorphism between $H$ and $H^*$. Moreover, it satisfies $\kappa(t_{\alpha_1},k) = \alpha(k)$ for all $k$, not just some specific $k_1$.

Isomorphism only gives 1-to-1 mapping right? Why uniformness $t_\alpha$ of the mapping itself?

What do you mean by uniformness?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

This has nothing to do with Lie algebras, it is rather straightforward (bi)linear algebra.
Let $V$ be a $K$-vector space with a bilinear form $(\cdot,\cdot):V\times V \rightarrow K$. For $v,w\in V$, calling $l_v(w) :=(v,w)$ we note that $l_v \in V^*$ and that the map $v \mapsto l_v$ is a linear homomorphism $V \rightarrow V^*$. If $(\cdot, \cdot)$ is non-degenerate then that map is injective; if $V$ has finite dimension, it (consequently) is an isomorphism. In other words, each linear form $l\in V^*$ is of the form $l_v$, for a uniquely determined $v$.
Maybe you even accept that, but let's make it very concrete to tackle your confusion. Say $V=\mathbb R^3$ and $(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the standard dot product. Now all I'm claiming is that if you give me any linear form $\alpha\in V^*$, I will be able to produce one and only one $v =\pmatrix{v_1\\v_2\\v_3}\in V$ such that for all $w\in V$, $\alpha(w) = (v,w) = v_1w_1+v_2w_2+v_3w_3$. How do I do that? Well, I set $v_i :=\alpha(e_i)$. Go through this example to see what everything above means concretely.
To tackle the confusion in your last paragraph, let's take a very concrete $\alpha \in V^*$, say $$\alpha(\pmatrix{v_1\\v_2\\v_3}) = 2v_1-v_2+v_3.$$
Now take $k_1 = \pmatrix{1\\0\\0}$ and $k_2=\pmatrix{0\\1\\0}$. You say you see that e.g. for $t_1 = \pmatrix{2\\0\\17}$ and $t_2=\pmatrix{12\\-1\\8.5}$, we have $(t_1, k_1)=\alpha(k_1)$ and $(t_2, k_2)=\alpha(k_2)$, but obviously $t_1 \neq t_2$.
Well yes, but neither $t_1$ nor $t_2$ is the right $t$ such that our $\alpha$ is $l_t$. The one and only one right $t$ for this $\alpha$ would be $t=\pmatrix{2\\-1\\1}$. It happens to be the case that for any $t$ of the form $\pmatrix{2\\*\\*}$, here we have $\alpha(e_1)=(t, e_1)$; and for any $t$ of the form $\pmatrix{*\\-1\\*}$, we have $\alpha(e_2)=(t, e_2)$. But to describe our $\alpha$, we need both, and (here) one more linearly independent vector on which to evaluate it. And then you'll see that this one, that works on all $w\in V$ (for which we need to at least check it on a basis), is the unique $t=\pmatrix{2\\-1\\1}$.

$t=\pmatrix{2\-1\1}$, right? by definition of that specific $\alpha$. The paragraph above the example is easier to understand.  Where does that 3 comes from? $t_1$ and $t_2$ are not even in H.

I'll close the question. The discussion with Tri kind of helped me understand the issue. It's just I need more practice on how isomorphism is used.

Yes, the $3$ was a typo (twice), sorry about that -- it's corrected now. -- There is no $H$ in my question. My point is this works for any vector space, here $V=\mathbb R^3$. If your $H$ is a real three-dimensional vector space, after choice of basis, there you go, but the idea was that you see this in generality.
